# Undistort image using python in raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, camera, raspberry-pi

see this link:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495867/raspberry-picalibrate-camera-and-undistortion-of-image?noredirect=1#comment60608319_36495867)...that is my code and now i got correct RMS,camera matrix and distortion coefficient without any error after capturing chessboard pattern image..and also every time when i run i got same output as below:

```
processing image10.jpg... ok
processing image3.jpg... ok
processing image2.jpg... ok
processing image8.jpg... ok
processing image7.jpg... ok
processing image1.jpg... ok
processing image5.jpg... ok
processing image4.jpg... ok
RMS: 0.137022853601
camera matrix:
[[ 271.40850489    0.          306.38705314]
 [   0.          271.08688021  234.03565551]
 [   0.            0.            1.        ]]
distortion coefficients:  [ -3.55461489e-01   1.45402260e-01  -1.33385142e-03   1.63603888e-04
  -2.96650946e-02]
```

when i put this parameters in undist.py file as shown in link..it give me image with more fisheye effect...so where is problem?..how i get normal image without fisheye effect?why it shows me a image with more fisheye effect than it has inplace of removing fisheye effect,when i add this parameters to undist.py(means image shows in more round shape than it is already)?where i have to do changes?plz help me..Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you could summarize your current version of the code  together with a sample image you are processing.

Comment: i have update current code and sample image of chess board and also attach current output image in above link..plz check it and suggest me the solution.

Comment: i have captured img using webcam when run undist.py file is 640*480 size image..is there any impact of this size image on camera matrix and distortion coefficient?if yes then what changes i need to do in code and in which file?plz suggest me.